# Add new dynamic field to schema without reindexing

Tags: solr

Is it possible to add more dynamic fields to a schema without reindexing everything? There's already a bunch of dynamic fields in the schema:

```xml
<dynamicField name="*_i" type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true" termVectors="false" termPositions="false" termOffsets="false"/>
<dynamicField name="*_l" type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true" termVectors="false" termPositions="false" termOffsets="false"/>
<dynamicField name="*_t" type="text"   indexed="true"  stored="true" termVectors="false" termPositions="false" termOffsets="false"/>
<dynamicField name="*_s" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true" termVectors="false" termPositions="false" termOffsets="false"/>
```

And now we need to be able to store a `float`. Would adding a new dynamic field to the schema like this:

```xml
<dynamicField name="*_f" type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true" termVectors="false" termPositions="false" termOffsets="false"/>
```

Will that require rebuilding the index (in particular with Solr 4.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this dynamic field to be considered for the existing documents then yes you need to re-index all.

If you are fine with updates of existing documents will cover the thing or You are list bothered about the existing documents then you can simply add this dynamic Field and restart the server.

In the second case you need not have to re-index.

Comment: The new field is optional and will only added to new documents if applicable. So I take it's okay to add the dynamic field without reindexing, right?